# php code - woocommerce ignore product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Sorry I am somewhat of a novice at php but am wondering if someone might be able to point me in the right direction. I have a function created that works perfect. It is used in woocommerce and for a certain category only, removes the 'add to cart' button and replaces with a link to another page. There is one product in this category that I need to ignore the function for. The working code is:

```
function fishing_buttons(){

// die early if we aren't on a product
if ( ! is_product() ) return;

$product = get_product();

if ( has_term( 'fishing', 'product_cat' ) ){

    // removing the purchase buttons
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30 );

    // adding our own custom text
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'fishing_priceguide' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'fishing_priceguide', 30 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'fishing_priceguide', 30 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'fishing_priceguide', 30 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'fishing_priceguide', 30 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'fishing_priceguide', 30 );} // fishing_buttons 
    add_action( 'wp', 'fishing_buttons' );

    /**
     * Our custom button
     */
    function fishing_priceguide(){
        echo do_shortcode( '[pl_button type="fish" link="http://localhost:8888/fish/fishing-price-guide/"]View our price guide[/pl_button]' );
    } // fishing_priceguide
```

The product ID is 1268 that I want to ignore (i.e. keep the add to cart button). Is it possible to include an 'and' condition in the if statement? I have tried 
 `if ( has_term( 'fishing', 'product_cat' ) && product_id != '1268' ){`
But have not had any success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`product` means nothing as you have it. `$product` is an object and the product ID is stored as the class variable `$product->id`. Therefore your code should be:

```
if ( has_term( 'fishing', 'product_cat' )&& $product->id != '1268' )
```

Also what hook is `fishing_buttons` attached to? You can probably just use the `global $product` but don't need to retrieve the product again.

```
function fishing_buttons(){

global $product;
if ( has_term( 'fishing', 'product_cat' )&& $product->id != '1268' ){
// your stuff
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'fishing_buttons' );
```